# vba syntax to pull values from combobox

Tags: vba, combobox

I am using activex controls in my powerpoint using VBA.

CB -> Combo box
TF1, TF2 -> Text box

```
rst.Open "SELECT [TF1],[TF2] FROM TABLE1 where [CB]='Happy New Year';", cnn, adOpenStatic
```

works fine.

But as the combo box will change values I need to write a code which will populate my text box accordingly.

So I used the following code which is not working

```
rst.Open "SELECT [TF1],[TF2] FROM TABLE1 where [CB]='" & Str(Me.ComboBox1.Value) & "';", cnn, adOpenStatic
```

When I execute I get type mismatch error.

Need all you help in fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

I've testet in Powerpoint 2010 and

```
Me.ComboBox1.Text
```

was working for me, but

```
Me.ComboBox1.Value
```

is fine too.

I think, this should work properly.

```
rst.Open "SELECT [TF1],[TF2] FROM TABLE1 where [CB]='" & Me.ComboBox1.Value & "';", cnn, adOpenStatic
```

Note:
Don't use the 'str()' function. It's just for converting numbers to string.
Source:
http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/str.php

Comment: Can you please share the entire syntax that you used ?

Comment: Don't use the 'str()' function. It's just for converting numbers to string.
Your 'str()' causes the type-error.
http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/str.php

Comment: Yes thankyou. Me.ComboBox1.Text worked. 

The required syntax is 

rst.Open "SELECT [TF1],[TF2] FROM TABLE where [ProjectName]= '" & Me.ComboBox1.Text & "'", _
    cnn, adOpenStatic

Comment: Your text is not so good to read but i think your problem is solved. Good to hear.

One hint for you:
Watch out for case-sensitive string and whitespaces.
Use `trim`, `replace(" ", "")` and `upperCase / lowerCase` or `uCase / lCase`.

Oh and if my answer helped, i would be grateful, if you check it.